# Polymorphic Table for comments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I am building out an app where multiple objects will have comments. I originally designed the app where the only thing that could have comments were Posts, but since have changed directions to make comments polymporphic.

Here is my `Post` model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Bootsy::Container

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post_category
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable

  validates_presence_of :post_category, :user

  scope :sticky, -> { where sticky: true }
  scope :not_sticky, -> { where sticky: false }
  scope :for_category, ->(cat_id) { where post_category_id: cat_id }

  def is_new?
    created_at > Time.now - 24.hours
  end
end
```

Comments Model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Bootsy::Container

  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Currently, `Posts` (posts in a forum) are namespaced and for my other `commentable` objects, they won't be namespaced. Should I have a `CommentsController` in the namespaced `forum` controllers directory **and** a `CommentsController` in the main controllers directory?

My routes look like this (so far):

```
  # Recently added
  resources :comments,    only: [:create]

  namespace :forum do
    resources :posts,   only: [:index] do
      resources :comments, only: [:create]
    end
    resources :post_categories, only: [:index] do
      resources :posts,   only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to have separate views for comments on each model then in my opinion you should have both controllers.